# Understanding .Single()

Tags: c#, asp.net

[This is a really tough one to Google.]

Browsing sample code i'm seeing a usage i don't understand:

```
var orderRow = order.Rows.Single();
```

Rows is an enumerable and usually one would iterate using a foreach loop. Is the .Single a workaround for cases where, for whatever reason, the foreach can't be (or need not) be used?

thx

In the time since the OP i've learned a bit more about usage that'll help other hits to this question:

```
var option = options.OfType<AdditionalLocationsOption>().SingleOrDefault();
if (option != null){
...stuff
}
```

Comment: presumably Rows is an IEnumerable containing exactly a single row....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ's [`Single` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) returns the single element in a collection.

This would be written in `Rows` is known to contain *exactly* one row.
If it's empty, or if it has more than one row, an exception will be thrown.

If you know that the collection has exactly one element, this code is simpler than a `foreach` loop and makes its intentions clearer.

Comment: @justSteve, also learn `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `FirstOrDefault`. `First` is useful when there could be *more* than one item but you're only interested in the first. The `OrDefault` variants will return the default values for the type (null for a class, 0 for an int, etc.) if no elements are present, but `SingleOrDefault` will still throw if more than one element is present.

Comment: I'm a Java guy. This reminds me of the utility method I use all the time in Google's guava collections: `Iterables.getOnlyElement`. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement(java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: As that you call out "LINQ's" - i follow that .Single is often use in Linq expressions but, it's not exclusive to LINQ, is it?

Comment: @just: What does that mean? LINQ is a set of methods.  `Single` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks is right on.  A practical example is if you want to retrieve an item from a database with a specific ID.  You know that your table should only contain one row with this ID (if not, something bad has happened and an exception should be thrown).  You could do orders.Where( x => x.ID == myID ).Single() and it will return the one requested order.

SinglgeOrDefault puts a little twist on things... it throws an exception if there are more than 1 items in the collection but not if there are 0 items.  In that case it returns null or whatever the default value is for the type being returned